# How to a include Stylus Libraries with grunt-contrib-stylus?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, stylus, jeet-grid

How to a include Stylus Libraries with grunt-contrib-stylus?

I would like to add Jeet & Rupture to my stylus setup.

I have run npm install `--save-dev rupture` & `npm install --save-dev jeet`

But I am not sure on how to have them used by the stylus setup, this is what I have:

```
// Compiles Stylus to CSS
    stylus: {
      server: {
        options: {
          paths: [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/components',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets'
          ],
          "include css": true
        },
        files: {
          '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.styl'
        }
      }
    },
```

And this is how I am calling Jeet.

```
@import 'jeet';
```

But I get this `error failed to locate @import file jeet.styl`

```
>>     6| @import 'jeet';
>> --------------^
```

Comment: I have managed to get autoprefixer-stylus working using `use: [
            function() { return require('autoprefixer-stylus')('last 2 versions', 'ie 8'); }
          ],` form here https://gist.github.com/sapegin/6987625 But I still can't figure out how to get jeet and rupture working.

Answer (score 2):

For those that are interested I have found a solution:

```
stylus: {
      server: {
        options: {
          use: [
            require('jeet'),
            require('rupture'),
            function() { return require('autoprefixer-stylus')('last 2 versions', 'ie 8'); }
          ],
          paths: [
            './node_modules/rupture',
            './node_modules/jeet/stylus',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/components',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets'
          ],
          // "include css": true,
          // use: jeet()
        },
        files: {
          '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.styl'
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Is this assuming that they are installed via npm instead of bower or something else?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to include a full path to the library, eg.

```
@import '/bower_components/jeet/stylus/jeet'
```

You can do this for all your required libraries.